# 6v between vin and pin even though pin is off

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a arduino uno and i am trying to make a lightstrip work.
i have made a program for this but when i turn off the pins to make the light
strip turn off it still glows.
red the reason is that there is still 6v between vin and the port even though there should be 0v.
here is my code

```
void setup() {
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}

void loop() {
}
```

any way to fix this

Comment: Please show us your circuit, so that we can see, how the lightstrip is connected. The problem must lie there

Comment: A low output is (almost) the same as ground. Between VIN and GND you will get VIN. Between VIN and an IO pin set to LOW you will get VIN - since LOW and GND are the same.

Answer (score 0):

That would be the correct reading.
If (LOW) 0 is near GND.
**All your measurements should be from(against) GND** 
Never connect any pins into voltage before regulator(V-in) or voltage over 5v (I usualy target 4.6v as MAX voltage to give myself a margin of error) and even that should only be done in the event of input or high (1) mode.
You are lucky if your multi-meter had big enough resistance and did not damage your Arduino yet.
Arduinos pins have no real protection and very little resistance when in output mode.
Even though pro's keep saying that it is pointless I find that when connecting items sensitive to even tiny current using NPN transistor i tend to use pull-down 10K-ish resistor against GND